# VB.Net Add value from datagridview to listbox in another form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, listbox

I have a trouble on VB.Net desktop programming, I have a Form with a ListBox, Called Form1, this form have a button that will appear another form with DataGridView inside that new Form, we will call this as Participant. Then I have a scenario, when User click the Button, it will call the Participant Form, and when user click the datagridview row in the Participant Form, it will get the value from that row and add the value to the ListBox in Form1, I have done getting the value from the row, but I can't add the value to the ListBox. This is my code to help you understand what I have done.

This is the code that will call the Participant Form :

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    Dim myForm As New Participant
    If myForm Is Nothing Then
        myForm = New Participant
    End If
    myForm.Show()
End Sub
```

And this is the code that will add the value from DataGridView in Participant Form to the ListBox in Form1

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim yourColumnIndex As Int32 = 1
    If e.ColumnIndex = yourColumnIndex Then

        participant_Share = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
        Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(participant_Share)
    End If
End Sub
```

But this code cannot insert the value to the ListBox, Please help me if you know how to solve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can change `Participant` constructor to accept a `ListBox` as parameter and store it in a local variable.

```
Private yourListBoxReference As ListBox

Public Sub New(ByVal yourListBox As ListBox)

    InitializeComponent()

    yourListBoxReference = yourListBox

End Sub
```

So you can call this form as:

```
myForm = New Participant(yourListBox)
```

And use the local variable to add an element to your `ListBox`:

```
yourListBoxReference.Items.Add(participant_Share)
```